# Battery-charging file on a SGS4 (when phone turned off)?

Tags: android

I have a **Samsung Galaxy S4** and I want to change the file that displays that small battery, but not the one on the top of the screen but the big one when the phone is charging and plugged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember correctly it is this one:

```
/system/bin/lpm
```

Comment: Or something similar containing the "lpm" in the file.